# Language Translator Using Google API in Python

Tags: python, google-api, language-translation

I have used this code from geeksforgeeks (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/language-translator-using-google-api-in-python/), I am trying to run it and it runs without any error, and it prints out:

```
Speak 'hello' to initiate the Translation !
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

but when i say "hello" it does not recognize it and do not start listening for translation.

I have imported all the modules, tried updating every one of them, and also Im using a macbook m1 pro.

And heres the code:

```
import speech_recognition as spr
from googletrans import Translator
from gtts import gTTS
import os
 
 
# Creating Recogniser() class object
recog1 = spr.Recognizer()
 
# Creating microphone instance
mc = spr.Microphone()
 
 
# Capture Voice
with mc as source:
    print("Speak 'hello' to initiate the Translation !")
    print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    recog1.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.2)
    audio = recog1.listen(source)
    MyText = recog1.recognize_google(audio)
    MyText = MyText.lower()
 
# Here initialising the recorder with
# hello, whatever after that hello it
# will recognise it.
if 'hello' in MyText:
     
    # Translator method for translation
    translator = Translator()
     
    # short form of english in which
    # you will speak
    from_lang = 'en'
     
    # In which we want to convert, short
    # form of hindi
    to_lang = 'hi'
     
    with mc as source:
         
        print("Speak a stentence...")
        recog1.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.2)
         
        # Storing the speech into audio variable
        audio = recog1.listen(source)
         
        # Using recognize.google() method to
        # convert audio into text
        get_sentence = recog1.recognize_google(audio)
 
        # Using try and except block to improve
        # its efficiency.
        try:
             
            # Printing Speech which need to
            # be translated.
            print("Phase to be Translated :"+ get_sentence)
 
            # Using translate() method which requires
            # three arguments, 1st the sentence which
            # needs to be translated 2nd source language
            # and 3rd to which we need to translate in
            text_to_translate = translator.translate(get_sentence,
                                                     src= from_lang,
                                                     dest= to_lang)
             
            # Storing the translated text in text
            # variable
            text = text_to_translate.text
 
            # Using Google-Text-to-Speech ie, gTTS() method
            # to speak the translated text into the
            # destination language which is stored in to_lang.
            # Also, we have given 3rd argument as False because
            # by default it speaks very slowly
            speak = gTTS(text=text, lang=to_lang, slow= False)
 
            # Using save() method to save the translated
            # speech in capture_voice.mp3
            speak.save("captured_voice.mp3")    
             
            # Using OS module to run the translated voice.
            os.system("start captured_voice.mp3")
 
        # Here we are using except block for UnknownValue
        # and Request Error and printing the same to
        # provide better service to the user.
        except spr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Unable to Understand the Input")
             
        except spr.RequestError as e:
            print("Unable to provide Required Output".format(e))
```

Comment: How did you debug this? At what point is the code getting stuck? Did you bypass the speech recognition and see if the translation works directly? Did you verify that the speech recognition is or isn't working? Basically you have given us no useful info on how to debugged this. I highly suggest debugging your programs before trying anything else. PyCharm is free and has a great debugger: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html

Comment: Also I recommend against using code from GeeksForGeeks; its quality isn't really that great, as evidenced by your issue. It's likely it was written with older versions of the libraries in mind, and hasn't been updated to work correctly with the current versions of those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
from gtts import gTTS
from io import BytesIO
from pygame import mixer
import time

def speak():
    mp3_fp = BytesIO()
    tts = gTTS('KGF is a Great movie to watch', lang='en')
    tts.write_to_fp(mp3_fp)
    tts.save("Audio.mp3")
    return mp3_fp

mixer.init()
sound = speak()
sound.seek(0)
mixer.music.load(sound, "mp3")
mixer.music.play()
```